# R: Set data point size of PCA autoplot according to a value

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggfortify

I am using the `autoplot` function to make a PCA plot. This is the code:

```
library(ggfortify)
df <- iris[c(1, 2, 3)]
autoplot(prcomp(df), data=iris, colour = "Species")
```

I would like to use the `iris[c(4)]` to be used in a way that the size of each data point in the PCA plot corresponds to the value of `iris[c(4)]`. An example from the iris dataset: the data point 132 should have a bigger size than data point 1. Is this possible in `ggforitfy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass in the column name you want to size by as a string.

```
autoplot(prcomp(df), data=iris, colour = "Species", size = "Petal.Width")
```

[image]

You can then adjust sizing like ggplot2 normal:

```
+ scale_size_continuous(range = c(1,3))
```